# Spark code to protect from FileNotFoundExceptions?

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

> Is there a way to run my spark program and be shielded from files
>   underneath changing?

The code starts by reading a parquet file (no errors during the read):

```
val mappings = spark.read.parquet(S3_BUCKET_PATH + "/table/mappings/")
```

It then does transformations with the data e.g.,

```
val newTable = mappings.join(anotherTable, 'id)
```

These transformations take hours (which is another problem).

Sometimes the job finishes, other times, it dies with the following similar message:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 6 in stage 1014.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   6.3 in stage 1014.0 (TID 106820, 10.127.251.252, executor 5): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory:
>   s3a://bucket1/table/mappings/part-00007-21eac9c5-yyzz-4295-a6ef-5f3bb13bed64.snappy.parquet

We believe another job is changing the files underneath us, but haven't been able to find the culprit.

Comment: try running with speculative execution on.

Comment: This happens when another process is trying to write/modify parquet files in that directory. Make sure you read files after another process is completed.

Comment: Another problem about long running job, it's hard to suggest something without your job configuration.

Comment: What is your spark version ?   
             https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18883

Comment: enable speculative execution   ,spark.speculation=true

Comment: Do not think about enabling speculation with s3a as a destination. you will corrupt your output and not notice. Why? Task commit relies on rename() being fast and atomic. The way its mocked in s3a it is neither. Both workers may commit simultaneously, so the output will be corrupt mess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very complicated problem to solve here. If the underlying data changes while you are operating on the same dataframe the spark job will fail. The reason is when the dataframe was created the underlying RDD knew the location of the data and the DAG associated with it. Now if the underlying data suddenly changed by some job , RDD has no option but fail it.

One possibility of enable retry ,speculation etc but nevertheless the problem exists. Generally if you have a table in parquet and you want to read write at the same time, partition the table by date or time and then write will happen in the different partition while reading will happen in different partition.

Now with the problem of join taking long time. If you are reading the data from s3 then join and write back to s3 again the performance will be slower. Because now the hadoop needs to fetch the data from s3 first then perform the operation ( code not going to data ). Although the network call is fast, I ran some experiment with s3 vs EMR FS and found 50% slowdown with s3.

One alternative is to copy the data from s3 to HDFS and then run the join. That will shield you from the data overwriting and the performance will be faster.

One last thing if you are using spark 2.2 s3 write is painfully slow due to deprecation of DirectOutputCommiter. So that could be another reason for slowdown